# Send email to subscribers when article is published using mailchimp in Joomla

Tags: joomla3.0

I need to send email to subscribers when new article is published.
I have installed mailchimp.

Answer (score 0):

Mailchimp have a pretty in-depth API, I can't see any joomla add-ons to achieve what you require, but you could always write your own if that's an option?

http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/get-started-with-mailchimp-api-3/

They use the REST protocol

Comment: Thanks Nick, I will try this.